# New to Java but I am having Issues

Tags: java

I have been doing research on why Java keeps closing immediately upon opening it. I am on Windows 10 and running on a 64 bit. I did install the correct Java download for Windows 64 bit. I have uninstalled it and installed it about four times but nothing seemed to help. I also double checked to see if it was up to date and it was at the latest version. I am unsure why this problem is occurring.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you running java from the command line?

Comment: What do you mean by opening java? You don't really usually open java, you just write java code in an Integrated Development Environment which then runs your code. Can you be more specific with your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "Java keeps closing immediately upon opening it" ? Your program?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review your question and make sure it can be understood to someone who does not have any prior information about what you try to do

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly run java.exe from the jdk bin path. You must do it in command prompt. The main thing is if you are not using any IDE and trying to write your code in any editor then manually run it. then you have to set java path as environment variable.

- Watch this video to do that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1VxWWubxFo .
- Then write a simple java program , save it with .java extension.
- Then open cmd there where you have written the program by holding shift key and right click on the file explorer, you will see a option like open command window here.
- Then write `javac <your java file name with .java extension>`.
- Then write `java <your class name in the program>`. **Ignore these < > angle quotes**